# argument conversion in python need help doing for a challenge

Tags: python

Hello I'm a learning developer and I'm facing a challenge that i am so confused with it that i dont know where to even star from.

this is the challenge:

You'll probably want to use try and except on this one. You might have to not use the else block, though.
Write a function named squared that takes a single argument.
If the argument can be converted into an integer, convert it and return the square of the number (num ** 2 or num * num).
If the argument cannot be turned into an integer (maybe it's a string of non-numbers?), return the argument multiplied by its length. Look in the file for examples.

and in the coding section all there is is this:

```
# EXAMPLES
# squared(5) would return 25
# squared("2") would return 4
# squared("tim") would return "timtimtim"
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Convert to integer with `int()` and read its doc to find out how to use `try ... except` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some psuedo code to get you started:

```
def squared(num):
    try:
        # convert num to int
        # do multiplication logic
    except:
        # int conversion failed,
        # multiply num by its length

    return num
```

Some useful python docs you should read:

- [Getting the length of an object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)
- [Conversion to int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)
- [Try and except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions)

Comment: thanks so much for you're response.  can you please give me the complete code for this. in the challenge i did everything i could but the code is still not passing. i would appreciate it if you could give me the complete code. thanks in advance.